# Apache Sling - passing request object as part of doPost

Tags: servlets, aem, sling

Can someone explain and provide code snippet for passing request body (maybe it can accept value Object) as part of apache sling **doPost** method -

request :
{ "XDPCont" : "XDP sample string"}

Response :

I have tried with below code but it did't work.

```
@Override
protected void doPost(final SlingHttpServletRequest req,
                     final SlingHttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    final Resource resource = req.getResource();
    resp.getOutputStream().println(resource.toString());
    resp.getOutputStream().println(
            "This content is generated by the HelloServlet POST"+req.getRequestParameter("XDPCont"));
}
```

Can you please explain with an working code.

Comment: What do you mean with `did not work`? Did you get an exception? The wrong result? Something in the `error.log`?

Comment: I think I see what the problem is. You want to read the JSON in the body but you use the `getRequestParameter` method. Those methods only contain URL parameters and not the body. You can get the body from the requests "reader". If you want to get the body you can do something like this: `req.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));`. This will give you the whole JSON string. Further parsing could be done with Gson.